# Bootstrap - label with multiple words gets broken into multiple lines

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a form with a couple inputs and their labels in an ASP.NET view, but the labels that are multiple words, get broken into multiple lines in full scale (if it's one very long word it doesn't so the length shouldn't be a problem), and I'd like to have it as one line.

Here's an example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row ">

               <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyAttr,"MyLabel", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1 label-operation" })
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyAttr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyAttr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                               </div>
                            </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyAttr2, "My Label Two", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1 label-operation" })
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyAttr2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyAttr2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

[image]

(The label-operation CSS class is my own,so far it only has the font-size set in it)

```
.label-operation {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested, I have tried different col-md values before, the next happens:

[image]

Comment: That is unusual bootstrap label behaviour. It seems something else might be conflicting. You need to provide some reproducable code including HTML and CSS etc so that we can better diagnose your issue - what you have provided is not enough.

Comment: have you tried to adjust col-md-1 to col-md-2? @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyAttr2, "My Label Two", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 label-operation" })

Comment: @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyAttr,"MyLabel", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1 label-operation" }) try changing col-md-1 to col-md-2 or col-md-3

Comment: I have tried different col-md values, the label does become a one liner, but it gets thrown a bit to the right

Comment: As I've suggested before - you really need to provide us with more code (your HTML and CSS) otherwise this is going to be extremely difficult to troubleshoot - as you can see, people are stabbing in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing is get rid of the "col-md-1" entirely and set the left padding in my custom ".label-operation" CSS class to 15px. Now the labels look as intended in both full scale and in responsive cases.

Answer (score 1):

The class `.form-group` functions in a way the same as a row would. As the form field them selfs are already quite small the class `.col-md-1` made sure the label is only 1/12th of that rows width.

As on why the first element doens't display every small, it's because it contains no breaking spaces, so it remains on one line.

To fix this you could change the class `.col-md-1` to `.col-auto`, which would make the column af wide as the content.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code Maybe this is because you are using the "col-md-1" class in code that makes the width responsive in tabs and other devices but not on a desktop browser.

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyAttr2, "My Label Two", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label label-operation" })
```